# Questions wrt taproot's message digest signing

Tags: taproot, schnorr-signatures

[BIP-341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) describes how to construct the message to be signed for taproot (subsection Common signature message). It mostly makes sense but I have a couple of quick questions:

- Is the ext_flag 0 when spending default key path and 1 if spending with a script?
- In the 'Data about this input' it says that scriptPubKey is always 35 bytes. How so? I would assume it is (a) "OP_1 OP_PUSHDATA(1) <32 bytes>" so 34 bytes. Does "serialized as script inside CTxOut" mean that we need another byte for the length of (a), thus making it 35 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ext_flag` is (currently) only `0` for key path spends. The only defined script path spend (Tapscript, [BIP342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki)) [sets `ext_flag` to `1`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki#common-signature-message-extension).

The size of a Taproot ScriptPubKey is indeed always 35 bytes because there is:

- 1 byte for the size of the script
- 1 `OP_1`
- A 32 bytes push (which is 33 bytes accounting for the length prefix)